Counter-example for removing intervals with most intersections in the scheduling problem

Input: Set I of n intervals on a line
Output: Largest subset of mutually non-overlapping intervals from I

Only concerned with correctness and considering an alternative to the known greedy approach. While I understand the standard earliest-finish-time greedy algorithm is optimal, I'm trying to disprove this alternative strategy:

Remove the interval with the most intersections
If there's a tie, remove the longer interval
If the length is the same, remove one at random
Recompute the number of intersections
Repeat until no intersections remain

I need a counter-example to show why this fails (if it does).

Do you care about the maximum size of the intervals considered in the subset? Or just maximizing the number of intervals works for you?

I am going off on the assumption here that you only want to maximize the number of mutually non-overlapping subsets.
Consider the following set of intervals
$$\{[0,2],[1,3],[2,4],[3,6],[5,8],[6,9],[7,10]\}$$
Clearly $[3,6]$ has the most intersections ($4$ intersections) so that goes off. The remainign set is now $$\{[0,2],[1,3],[2,4],[5,8],[6,9],[7,10]\}$$
Now each of the intervals have $2$ intersections, but the ones in $A:=\{[5,8],[6,9],[7,10]\}$ has larger sizes so one of them gets removed. Then one of the ones in $B:=\{[0,2],[1,3],[2,4]\}$ gets removed. Again one of the ones in $A$ gets removed, and finally one of the ones in $B$ gets removed.
Finally, we are left with one interval from $A$ and one interval from $B$. So your algorithm gives $2$ as the answer.
But clearly $\{[0,2], [3,6], [7,10]\}$ is a larger solution.
Here's a badly drawn image of the starting intervals.

